# ARC assigning instance variable init or awakeFromNib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to initialise a variable in my `init` method, but it seems to get deallocated when the call chain reaches `awakeFromNib`. I've read several threads and far too many seem to share the same confusion - something that should be really simple and straightforward... :(.

```
- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    if (self) {
      self.customObject = [CustomObject currentInstance]; //OK
    }  
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.customObject someMethod]; //here self.customObject is nil?
    //self.customObject = [CustomObject currentInstance]; // Why should I do this here?
}
```

Nothing fancy about the declarations, in my `.m` file there's. I don't want to assign the property in `awakeFromNib` without understanding the *reason behind*.

```
@property (strong) CustomObject *customObject;
```

## CustomObject instantiation .m file

```
static CustomObject customObject;

@implementation CustomObject {

+ (instancetype)initMockCustomObject {
     customObject = (CustomObject*)[OCMockObject mockForClass:[CustomObject class]];
}
+ (instancetype)currentInstance {
   if ( customObject == nil) { [NSException raise...]; }
    return customObject;
    }
}
```

`initMockCustomObject` has already been called in AppDelegate.

Edit: added the actual super call to `initWithNibName` method in `init`.
Edit2: added the singleton instance

Comment: Silly question but is your `init` method actually called before `awakeFromNib` is called? If so, is it the same `self` pointer?

Comment: Yes and yes. I changed to even use _customObject directly.

Comment: The docs for `awakeFromNib` state you must call `[super awakeFromNib]` though I'm doubt that is related to this issue.

Comment: @rmaddy ok still same. Does it help to say that CustomObject is declared as static in it's .m file? Subsequent calls to [CustomObject currentInstance] yields exactly the same instance - that part should be 'OK'.

Comment: How are you creating CustomObject currentInstance?  dispatch_once?

Comment: @greg in this particular case it's been instantiated with OCMock. Will update the question with that info.

Comment: You're not returning `self` from `init`. Please include your _real_ code. How are you arranging for `init` to be called, and how have you verified that it is indeed being called?

Comment: Usually you don't init a singleton. You call currentInstance and if customObject is nil, it is created. Method names starting with init are used for methods that initialize, not allocate, objects. The * is missing in the declaration of customObject. customObject is not initialized. If I were the compiler I would be confused. Or is your code fragment not what you really did?

Comment: You can clean up singleton creation even further by using dispatch_once.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your input. I've created a sandbox project with the absolute minimum, and I found that I had a object in one of my parent NIB, that was of the same type as MyViewController, causing this problem. Closing this question as it's too app specific. The fundamental question of initialising variables in init is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your input. I've created a sandbox project with the absolute minimum, and I found that I had an object in one of my parent NIBs, that was of the same type as MyViewController, causing this problem. Closing this question as it's too app specific. The fundamental question of initialising variables in init is OK.